# Connect API to Sheets using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have managed to read from the sheets separately and I have managed to write to them, on the other hand I have access to the API, I'm just trying to put it all together and by the way learn Python, could someone help me?

I can't get the API response to be written in the sheet, it doesn't give me any error, it only tells me that it has connected but that it hasn't updated any column or any cell

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests
import json

#-------------------------------------------------------------------

def temilla ():

  BASE_URL = "https://company.com"

  token = 'RYE_'

  #headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)}
  PARAMS = {"employee_ids":"1007",
           #"employee_ids":"1388",
           #"business_unit_ids":"13",
           "start_date":"08/07/2022",
           "end_date":"09/07/2022"
           }
  headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token), "Api-version": "1.0"}
  response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params = PARAMS, headers = headers )

  result = [response.content]

  print(response.content)

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

 SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
 SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '146456464646464'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                         range="Horarios!A1:J20").execute()

print(result)

values = result.get('values', [])

temilla()

Cosilla = temilla()
#Cosilla = [["DIA",1],["AÑO",2022],["MES",9],["EMPLEADO","MARIANO"],["ACTIVO",True]]

request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                    range="Prueba-Escritura!a1:xa", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body= 
{"values":Cosilla}).execute()

#print(result)
#print(values)
print(request)
```

The response that the API gives me is similar to the following

b'[{"shift_id":2400298,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"alguno","employee_id":1007,"employee_code":"11111111","entry":"2022-08-07T11:30:00","exit":"2022-08-07T15:30:00"},{"shift_id":2400299,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"alguno","employee_id":1007,"employee_code":"1111111","entry":"2022-08-07T19:00:00","exit":"2022-08-07T23:00:00"}]'

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike for the help, the truth is that I am a bit lost learning Python, now I have another problem with another answer in Json

Comment: [{"employee_id":1007,"employee_code":"rsfsfsdfsfsfr","name":"uno","last_name":"ese quees",,"telephone1":"7475858858585858","bank_account":"Exx74774747474747474747","disability_level":"Select From Below","academic_education":"0","status":"Select From Below","level":"Select From Below","scale":"Select From Below","temporary_contract_reason":"Select From Below","additional_information":"","custom_field_collection":[{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"}]}]

Comment: with the fixes you provided me it won't let me transcribe that response from the server to sheet, if you prefer me to open another question I'll do it without problems, but I appreciate the help in any case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the values from `response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params = PARAMS, headers = headers )` to Google Spreadsheet.
- Sample value of it is `[{"shift_id":2400298,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"alguno","employee_id":1007,"employee_code":"11111111","entry":"2022-08-07T11:30:00","exit":"2022-08-07T15:30:00"},{"shift_id":2400299,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"alguno","employee_id":1007,"employee_code":"1111111","entry":"2022-08-07T19:00:00","exit":"2022-08-07T23:00:00"}]`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to put and get values to Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
# Retrieve values from requests as JSON.
response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params = PARAMS, headers = headers ) # This is from your script.
obj = response.json()

# Convert JSON to 2 dimensional array.
keys = obj[0].keys()
ar = []
for o in obj:
    temp = []
    for k in keys:
        temp.append(o[k] if k in o else "")
    ar.append(temp)

# Put values to Spreadsheet using googleapis.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = "###" # <--- Please set your Spreadsheet.
request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="Prueba-Escritura!a1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": [list(keys), *ar]}).execute()
print(request)
```

- In this modification,

  - Values from `response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params = PARAMS, headers = headers )` is converted to JSON. And, using this object, an array for putting into Spreadsheet is created.
  - Values are put from cell "A1" of the sheet of "Prueba-Escritura". If you want to change this, please modify `range="Prueba-Escritura!a1"`.
  - The header values are `keys = obj[0].keys()`. If you want to change this order, please modify this. If you want to use the specific order, please put the header row here like `keys = ['shift_id','business_unit_id','business_unit',,,]`.
  - This script puts the values including the header row. If you don't want to include the header row, please modify `[list(keys), *ar]` to `ar`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike for the help, the truth is that I am a bit lost learning Python, now I have another problem with another answer

Comment: [{"employee_id":1007,"employee_code":"rsfsfsdfsfsfr","name":"uno","last_name":"ese quees",,"telephone1":"7475858858585858","bank_account":"Exx74774747474747474747","disability_level":"Select From Below","academic_education":"0","status":"Select From Below","level":"Select From Below","scale":"Select From Below","temporary_contract_reason":"Select From Below","additional_information":"","custom_field_collection":[{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"}]}] –

Comment: with the fixes you provided me it won't let me transcribe that response from the server to sheet, if you prefer me to open another question I'll do it without problems, but I appreciate the help in any case –

Comment: @Fabrisimo About `Thank you very much Tanaike for the help, the truth is that I am a bit lost learning Python, now I have another problem with another answer`, if you are saying https://stackoverflow.com/q/73745434 , I asked a question.