# Connect API to Sheets response JSON

Tags: python, json, api, google-sheets

thanks to another user I have managed to connect an API through Python that serves me data and google sheets, the way to format the Json that this user taught me, for which I am very grateful he is not writing me data, I understand that the format of data is not designed for it, could someone tell me how to change the work that is done to json so that it is interpreted by the sheets API?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import requests
import json

#-------------------------------------------------------------------



BASE_URL = "https://apiserver.com/api"

token = '`xxxxxxxxxxx'

    #headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)}
PARAMS = {#"employee_ids":"xxxx",
             #"employee_ids":"xxxx",
             "business_unit_ids":"1",
             "start_date":"09/01/2022",
             "end_date":"09/14/2022"
             }
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token), "Api-version": "1.0"}
response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params = PARAMS, headers = headers )
obj = response.json()
result = [response.content]

keys = obj[0].keys()
ar = []
for o in obj:
    temp = []
    for k in keys:
        temp.append(o[k] if k in o else "")
    ar.append(temp)

    #print(response.content)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']

SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                             range="them!A1:J20").execute()

print(result)

values = result.get('values', [])


request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                        range="sheet!a1:xa", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": [list(keys), *ar]}).execute()


print(request)
```

I leave a sample of the answer with which it works and the answer with which it does not work

this yes

```
[{"shift_id":2400298,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"XXXXXXXX","employee_id":XXXXXXXX,"employee_code":"XXXXXXXX","entry":"2022-08-07T11:30:00","exit":"2022-08-07T15:30:00"},{"shift_id":2400299,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"XXXXXXXX","employee_id":XXXXXXXX,"employee_code":"XXXXXXXX","entry":"2022-08-07T19:00:00","exit":"2022-08-07T23:00:00"},{"shift_id":2402414,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"XXXXXXXX","employee_id":XXXXXXXX,"employee_code":"XXXXXXXX","entry":"2022-08-08T11:30:00","exit":"2022-08-08T16:00:00"},{"shift_id":2402415,"business_unit_id":10,"business_unit":"XXXXXXXX","employee_id":XXXXXXXX,"employee_code":"XXXXXXXX","entry":"2022-08-08T19:00:00","exit":"2022-08-08T23:30:00"},}]
```

not this one

```
[{"employee_id":XXXXXX,"employee_code":"XXXXXX","name":"XXXXXX","last_name":"XXXXXX","gender":"Undefined","marital_status":"Not_Defined","document_id":"XXXXXX","document_type":"Select From Below","authorization_type":"Select From Below","registration_time":"2022-09-14T00:00:00","address_road_type":"Select From Below","email":"XXXXXX","telephone1":"XXXXXX","bank_account":"XXXXXX","disability_level":"Select From Below","academic_education":"0","status":"Select From Below","level":"Select From Below","scale":"Select From Below","temporary_contract_reason":"Select From Below","additional_information":"","custom_field_collection":[{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"Undefined","value":""},{"name":"","value":""},{"name":"","value":""},{"name":"","value":""},{"name":"","value":""},{"name":"","value":""},{"name":"","value":""},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"},{"name":"","value":"UNDEFINED","value_id":"0"}]}]
```

I would appreciate the help

[image]

the terminal response is like this and it only lets me see up to a certain point, it does not update the sheet, I understand that when the Json response is formatted to send it to the Google Sheet API it does not pass it correctly so that be interpreted

---

instead of getting this output, committing the write to the sheet

```
{'spreadsheetId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'updatedRange': 'Empleados!A1:O528', 'updatedRows': 528, 'updatedColumns': 15, 'updatedCells': 7920}
```

i get this other error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Proyectos Python\Empleados-detalle-fconnect.py", line 74, in <module>
    range="Empleados-detalle!a1:xa", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": [list(keys), *ar]}).execute()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fabra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/values/Empleados-detalle%21a1%3Axa?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Invalid values[1][21]: list_value { values {
    struct_value {
      fields {
        key: "name"
        value {
          string_value: "Undefined"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "value"
        value {
          string_value: "UNDEFINED"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "value_id"
        value {
          string_value: "0"
        }
      }
```

Of course, I leave 3 images of how the written answer should look on the sheet, thanks again for your patience and help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: About your question, can you provide your expected situation as an image? Because, from your JSON data, I cannot understand your expected result. I apologize for this.

Comment: The problem is that I can't see the full response, but instead of telling me that it has been updated in sheets, I get this:

I already told you that it is so long that in the VisualStudio window I cannot go up to see the complete answer 
      ...fields {
        key: "value"
        value {
          string_value: "UNDEFINED"
        }
      }
      fields {
        key: "value_id"
        value {
          string_value: "0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
">
PS C:\Users\este\OneDrive\Escritorio\Proyectos Python>

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your expected situation. Can you provide your expected situation as an image?

Comment: No problem, I've added a picture to see if we can figure out what's going on, thank you so much again

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, you want to put the values from your JSON data to Google Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can you provide your expected situation as an image?

Comment: I have managed to read the complete answer from the terminal, I have put it at the end of the question

Comment: Of course, I leave 3 images of how the written answer should look on the sheet, thanks again for your patience and help

Comment: Thank you for replying. What are your added 3 images? I cannot understand them. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: In the  last rows of the question, It is possible that I am not understanding you, what do you mean by image?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `In the last rows of the question, It is possible that I am not understanding you, what do you mean by image?`, I couldn't understand your added 3 images. I apologize for this. Can you provide the sample output situation you expect using your sample input values?

Comment: Hello again, in the last 3 images you can see how I need the data to be written in sheets, on the other hand I leave here the JSON response provided by the API, to try to better clarify everything. In the other question that you answered magnificently, the writing on the sheet worked perfectly, but it seems that the way you taught me to format the JSON response worked for that occasion,

Comment: but not for this one, looking at the answer it can be seen as a block with data defined for the query and another block of data not defined at the moment and I think that when you try to format the response in the way that worked last time, now you don't get it

I hope you can help me, I don't know who else to ask for help

Comment: I have left again at the end of this question after the last photos, the answer that the server gives me

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.